# What is the difference between the tags [std] and [c++-standard-library]?

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

When should I use either the tag [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std) (of which [stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdlib) is a synonym) or [c++-standard-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-standard-library)? According to their wiki pages, they refer both to the C++ Standard Library.

If there isn't any difference between these two tags, I would like to request to map one to the other as a synonym.

Comment: The [[tag:stdlib]] tag you had originally mentioned doesn't actually exist. It is a synonym that remaps to [[tag:std]]. I've updated your question along these lines, though, because this is still a good question and a valid point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official name (from the language spec) is the *C++ standard library*. Symbols that are defined as part of the standard library are included in the `std` namespace, so it is common for users to refer to it as either of those names, or the much older "Standard Template Library" (or simply [stl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stl)).

I think that [c++-standard-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-standard-library) should be the main tag, and [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std) (along with its synonym [stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdlib)) as synonyms of that tag. (Also, [c++-standard-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-standard-library) also has better tag info, IMHO.)

Comment: Tag info shouldn't factor into the decision; I can trivially copy that to whichever tag we decide to make the "master". It's all about what text we want to show up. I agree with you, though, that [[tag:c++-standard-library]] makes more sense, and that [[tag:std]] and [tag:stdlib]] should be merged into it. I guess I'll stop short of merging [[tag:stl]] into it, too, since that'll surely bring out some pitchfork-bearing pedants...

Comment: Since no counter-arguments were brought, I am in favor of merging the tags. Do you (or @CodyGray ) want to submit an [application](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=Suggested)? I do not have the necessary privileges for this.

Comment: You are kind of forgetting that the name `stdlib` is already taken since the early 1970s, long before C++ was invented... `stdlib.h` ring a bell?

Answer (score 3):

I went through the list of questions tagged [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std) and a overwhelming majority is related to [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), which is fine. However, it looks like there are a lot of questions without C++ to, most evidently:

- 94 questions that are also tagged [with [c]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstd%5D+-%5Bc%2B%2B*%5D+%5Bc%5D+is%3Aq+&mixed=0)
- 133 questions that have neither [[c] nor [c++*]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstd%5D+-%5Bc%2B%2B*%5D+-%5Bc%5D+is%3Aq+&mixed=0)

I don't know much about C/C++ but I have deleted a lot of "no longer needed" comments complaining about how a poster has tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) for a C++ question, so I assume that these need to be disambiguated first before the tags are merged.

Given that [there are 227 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstd%5D+-%5Bc%2B%2B*%5D+is%3Aq+&mixed=0) that require our attention first, I think it is better to hold off on this tag merge until the tag is cleaned up and tidied for a merge with [c++-standard-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-standard-library).

Comment: At the [questions tagged with `std` and `c` but not `c++*`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstd%5D+-%5Bc%2B%2B*%5D+%5Bc%5D+is%3Aq+&mixed=0) the `std` tag should be replaced by [`libc`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/libc/info). Those with [neither `c` nor `c++*`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstd%5D+-%5Bc%2B%2B*%5D+-%5Bc%5D+is%3Aq+&mixed=0) probably need an additional `c++` tag. Is it possible to do a bulk edit?

Comment: @user5534993, there is no bulk editing. We need to check each post and update the tags only once we're sure that it's related to the C++ standard library. There are some cases like these, where it is related to Standard Deviation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290644/stats-properties-among-documents-r

Comment: Most importantly, `std` is a C++ keyword used for the standard library namespace, while `stdlib` is the name of a C header, which means something else entirely in that context, namely the use of `stdlib.h`.

Comment: @Lundin, if that's the case, then [std] and [stdlib] needs to be disambiguated as well, which kinda would be the outcome of this cleanup. The only difference is that, at the start [stdlib] needs to be removed as a synonym for [std]. I would propose calling [stdlib] as [c-stdlib], and rename [std] as [c++-standard-library]. (Feel free to suggest a different name for the C tag)

Comment: The thing is... std does not mean the "C++ standard library", it means the standard namespace. stdlib.h does not mean the "C standard library", it means one specific sub library of the C standard library. The most sensible name is [stdlib.h] if tags allow dots. That name is understood by C and C++ programmers both.

Comment: Sure, @Lundin, that should be fine. We do allow dots in tags. As long as we are sure that [stdlib.h] is understood by all, we should be good.

Comment: @BhargavRao Aye, that's the least ambiguous name you can give it. The `.h` is understood by C and C++ programmers and should prevent unrelated posts from including it for general "standard library" purposes.

Comment: `stdlib.h` is also the name of a [C compatibility header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header%23C_compatibility_headers) which is part of the *C++* Standard Library (see [C++20 final working draft](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf) section D.9). @Lundin do you suggest to create the identically named tag to be applicable for C and C++?