# Fixing the std and stdlib synonym tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

- The tag [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std) refers to the C++ namespace which is used for the standard library. This has been the case since 2011 when the tag wiki was added.
- `stdlib` is a C library `stdlib.h` which does not currently have its own tag.
- For some reason, [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std) and [stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdlib) tags are synonymous.

For this reason we have 102 questions tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std), the combinations not making any sense. Sometimes the question means `stdlib.h`, sometimes it means "standard C", sometimes it means something else.

All in all, there is a total of 259 questions not tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) but using [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std). Many appear to be C or C++ questions, but I also see questions about other languages, Python in particular.

Proposal:

- Rename [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std) to [c++-std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-std), [std-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std-keyword), [std-namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std-namespace) or a similar suitable name for the C++ keyword `std`.
- Remove synonym between [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std) and [stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdlib). Possibly rename [stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdlib) to [stdlib.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdlib.h).
- Possibly blacklist [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std), because it's a very ambiguous tag name.
- All 259 questions tagged [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std) but not [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) probably need to be reviewed.
- C++ questions regarding `stdlib.h` could do with a new tag [cstdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cstdlib). Not sure if that one should be synonymous with [stdlib.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdlib.h) or not.

---

EDIT

Clarification for those without domain knowledge:

- The C standard library contains of a bunch of "headers", sub-libraries of the library as whole. One such sub-library is `stdlib.h`, which contains misc general functions. There is no apparent use for a tag referring to the whole "C standard library".
- `libc` is a specific open source implementation of the C standard library, specific to Linux/POSIX. It has absolutely nothing to do with this topic. That tag is fine as it is, leave it be.
- C++ contains most of the C standard library (including `stdlib.h`).
- In C++, there is an alternative way of including C standard library headers by using `#include <cstdlib>` rather than `#include <stdlib.h>`. Even beginners are supposed to know this, so it is fine to make [cstdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cstdlib) and [stdlib.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdlib.h) synonymous. Apart from different ways to include it, it is the very same library in C and C++ both.
- In C++, all functions belonging to the C++ standard library are placed in the same namespace called `std`. So it is common to prefix C++ standard library functions or classes with `std::` when you use them. The `std` tag should supposedly be about the use of this namespace.
- There is in my opinion definitely a need for a tag for the `std` namespace, since failing to use the correct `using` statement to point at items in the `std` namespace leads to common problems. There's also a common FAQ regarding not to use `using namespace std`. All of these are C++ FAQ questions.

Comment: You said `stdlib(.h)` is a library for C, but your last bullet point indicates you think there are C++ questions regarding `stdlib(.h)`? And that somehow `cstdlib` would be understood as "C++ stdlib", rather than just "C stdlib"?

Comment: Related (possibly dupe): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398798/10871073

Comment: @AdrianMole Yep it's a dupe but the answers there aren't great. Hmm maybe someone messed up the synonyms lately, since that thread is very recent.

Comment: @Lundin I've also come across a number (quite a lot, actually) of suggested edits by the OP of that post - removing one or other of the C /C++ tags, or changing the tag to better fit the actual language. But yeah - the whole thing is a bit messy.

Comment: @TylerH `stdlib.h` is part of C++, since it's a C header. The languages uses slightly different ways of including this library though: C uses `#include <stdlib.h>` and C++ prefers to `#include <cstdlib>`. The former is valid in C++ but obsolete style, the latter is recommended. So I expect a bunch of tags called `cwhatever` for the corresponding C++ naming. It refers to the same headers though.

Comment: I think this brings a whole new idea into the view I wonder never was concerned really (at least I couldn't find posts but anyhow I'm sure it needs to be mentioned at least once anywhere on Meta). --- Why not creating "exclusive only" tags which you only can assign to a question post which is tagged with the appropriate language tag? For example, [tag:javascript] and [tag:std] conflict and the question can't be posted. This could solve the problem that [tag:std] is being used by other languages than [tag:c++].

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio But what if we actually want to use std with another language? For example [Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/). I don't think the advantage would be so big, one would need to maintain and update the tag dependencies.

Comment: @Trilarion The [tag:std] tag describes currently a [tag:c++]-specific feature only. Maybe we need a specific [tag:rust-std]?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio you are looking for hierarchies of tags. That option was rejected several times due the complexities that such system would bring.

Comment: Very minor point, but in C++, `include <cstdlib>` brings in all identifiers in namespace `std` and optionally also in the global namespace. `include <stdlib.h>` brings in all identifiers in the global namespace and also optionally in namespace `std`. I mention this only because you say that they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 10):

As I mention on from a [similar discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398798/4099593), [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std) is being used for multiple 'std's, I completely agree with the fact that this needs to be disambiguated.

> Rename [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std) to [c++-std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-std), [std-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std-keyword), [std-namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std-namespace) or a similar suitable name for the C++ keyword `std`.

For this, we can use the present [c++-standard-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-standard-library) itself. That particular tag has 783 questions and a tag wiki.

> rename [stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdlib) to [stdlib.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdlib.h).

This is one of my other concerns. Are we sure that "stdlib.h" won't be used by the C++ folks, mistaking it for the C++ std? If that's the case, then sure let's go ahead. If not, we should use probably use [c-stdlib.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-stdlib.h). Whenever there's confusion between two languages, using the prefixed tags is totally fine. <s>Alternatively, I am a fan of Cris Luengo's suggestion of using the present [libc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libc) instead. If we were to use this then, we can add the other suggestion [stdlib.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdlib.h) as a synonym for [libc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libc) if required.</s> The [libc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/libc) tag seems to be related to a very specific implementation of standard library, so that tag won't help us out here.

> C++ questions regarding `stdlib.h`

For this, I share the same concern as Tyler. However based on your reply, I understand that both C++ and C "stdlib.h" are the same. If this is the case, then we can create [cstdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cstdlib) as a synonym for [stdlib.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdlib.h)/[c-stdlib.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-stdlib.h) (or whatever that tag would be named). Having two separate tags for the same "stdlib.h" isn't required.

We can start off by breaking the synonym between [stdlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdlib) and [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std), and then manually sift through [the questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstd%5D+-%5Bc%2B%2B*%5D+is%3Aq+&mixed=0), to either add a [stdlib.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdlib.h)/[c-stdlib.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-stdlib.h) tag and remove the [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std) tag, or leave the [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std) as is (or just close the question if it is not on-topic).

For the burnination of [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std), that's not required. Once we merge it with [c++standard-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2bstandard-library), we can just remove the synonym and that should get rid of the tag.

Comment: I'm not sure we need a tag for one C header file. Also, most of these questions will be asking stuff about the C Standard Library, not specifically about `stdlib.h`, which is one header file in that library. I would recommend instead making a tag `c-standard-library` or `libc` (or both, one as a synonym of the other), if these don't exist yet.

Comment: Actually, there already is a [tag:libc] tag.

Comment: [tag:libc] does sound like a good option, I do prefer using existing tags instead of creating new ones. Thanks @Cris. Let me update my answer.

Comment: `c++-standard-library ... has 783 questions` Just saying, but [`stl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stl) has 14K+ questions, many of which would rightfully belong in `c++-standard-library` instead. But that would be the topic of another discussion, probably better kept out of this one here.

Comment: "Are we sure that "stdlib.h" won't be used by the C++ folks, mistaking it for the C++ std?" Yeah they won't, stdlib.h is a thing in C++ too. Technically it's the very same library in both languages. In C++ it may be referred to as `cstdlib` as well.

Comment: @CrisLuengo "I'm not sure we need a tag for one C header file." We absolutely do - the alternative is to create a tag for every function in that header file. Also the contents in the header file all behave in the same way. C++ ostream, istream, ofstream etc all work the same, so we only need a tag `iostream` for the whole header.

Comment: @CrisLuengo libc refers to a specific open-source standard C library implementation, which only works on Linux/POSIX. Compilers for other systems won't use it. That tag must be preserved for the use of the `libc` open source project specifically.

Comment: @Bhargav Rao `stdlib.h` has nothing to do with `libc` whatsoever. `stdlib.h` is a sub library of the whole standard C library. `libc` is an open source implementation of the whole standard C library.

Comment: I added some clarification to the question. Though maybe it is for the best if those without domain knowledge step away from this one.

Comment: The argument about [libc] sounds good, @Lundin, I can update my answer to remove that. Anyway, I did like your update to the post. It does clear out a lot my confusion at least. And of course, I can surely step away from this. I was trying to help you to clear these out, but if y'all can manage, then I'm totally fine with it.

Comment: @Lundin: Don't make assumptions about domain knowledge, please. I understand a tag for `iostream`, I understand a tag for `stdio.h` or `setjmp.h`, but I don't understand a tag for `stdlib.h`, which contains a grab-bag of functionality (`rand`, `malloc`, `system`, `atof` are all in there). Plus, I'm pretty sure that most people adding `stdlib` to their question are thinking of the "standard library", not of this specific header file.

Comment: @Lundin: The tag excerpt for [tag:libc] says "The C standard library consists of a set of sections of the ISO C standard which describe a collection of headers and library routines used to implement common operations, such as input/output and string handling, in the C programming language." -- I don't see any reference to any specific implementation. And it is common to refer to the C standard library as "libc", even when not using GCC. See for example [the first sentence in the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library). Might be correct or not, but it's common use.

Comment: @CrisLuengo That stdlib.h is a grab-bag is no fault of SO, it's just one of many flaws in the C standard library as whole, which was probably originally designed by grabbing random functions from a UNIX bag indeed. And then they gave it the most stupid, ambiguous name they could come up with.

Comment: Example of stdlib.h tag questions could be: calling malloc but forgetting to include stdlib.h (old FAQ), library design issues related to stdlib.h, questions about types (size_t etc) and macros (NULL etc) appearing in multiple standard headers etc etc. Probably not a high traffic tag, but it seems inconsistent to only have tags for some library headers and not for others.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I suppose "glibc" might be a more proper term. I haven't heard of anyone outside the Linux/POSIX world refer to "libc" meaning the standard library. Microsoft calls it the "C runtime library" for example.

Comment: @Lundin "but it seems inconsistent to only have tags for some library headers and not for others" why not make consistent towards the other end of the spectrum? No tags for any standard library. AFAIK, the standard library is included with the language, isn't it?

Comment: @Lundin: "Example of stdlib.h tag questions could be: calling malloc but forgetting to include stdlib.h (old FAQ), library design issues related to stdlib.h, questions about types (size_t etc) and macros (NULL etc) appearing in multiple standard headers etc etc." There's tags for [tag:malloc], [tag:size-t] and [tag:null]. Why would you want one tag on such disparate questions, whose only relationship is that they're **about the C Standard Library**?

Comment: @Braiam It is not necessarily included in the given compiler. There are a minimum of headers that all C compilers must support, but freestanding implementations (embedded systems) are free to leave out the majority of the standard library. And some headers are optional to all implementations. It's not very interesting to have a tag for "the whole standard library" but it is meaningful to have tags for individual headers.

Comment: @CrisLuengo So if I have a question about how to implement stdlib.h then how should I tag it?

Comment: @Lundin that seems to be a case for ditching the header tags in favor of tucking askers into including their target compiler in the question. Wouldn't including the compiler be more useful? BTW, how to implement a library would be too broad ;)

Comment: Regarding [tag:stl] mentioned above: Pretty much all of those questions are really about the standard library, though some (not few) still use STL as a name for (parts of) the latter. But I doubt that the actual STL as written by Alexander Stepanov in the 90s still has a lot of active users...

Comment: There is no point in having `c-stdlib.h`, with `c-` prefix as there most certainly is only that  `stdlib.h` which is defined in ISO/IEC 9899 The C Programming Language.

Comment: Various C runtime libraries in many implementations have been called `libc`. The problem with this is that it is *not* synonymous with the C *standard library*, but the C runtime with whatever vendor specific extensions there could be.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative acceptable tag name for [std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std) might be [namespace-std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/namespace-std).

I think that name might feel more natural to C++ programmers than [c++-std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-std), which seems a bit artificial and vague.

Comment: But what about Rust's std namespace? [tag:namespace-std] would be applicable then, too.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio I suppose it may end up one of those tags that must always be accompanied with the language tag? Getting the tag usage wiki right.